# Accessing a parent div's image element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

i'm so sure i have done this before, but somehow not getting it right this time. I have the below markup.

```
<div>
<p id="child">Nothing important here</p>
<img src="someimage.png">
</div>
```

The challenge is, i have only the 'child' id and using that i want to add a class 'hidden' to the image tag.

I tried this,

```
var parent = $('#child').parent();
$(parent +' img').addClass('hidden');
```

But this is not working. pls help to correct my code. Thanks!

Comment: `parent` is an object and not a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method or set the [context as the second argument in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context).

```
parent.find('img').addClass('hidden');

// or
$('img', parent).addClass('hidden');
```

---

**FYI :** In your code  `parent +' img'` results `[object Object] img` since `parent` is a jQuery object so that doesn't select any element.

---

Other alternative ways to get the elements,

1. Using jQuery [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method : `$('#child').siblings('img').addClass('hidden');`
2. Using [next adjuscent sibling selector](https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) : `$('#child + img').addClass('hidden');`

Comment: Thank you! i will try this out.